# RubyMotion cannot find simulator devices watch app

Tags: ios, rubymotion, watchos-5

I have a RubyMotion iOS app and watch app. The project root contains the iOS and a subdirectory `my_watch_app` contains the watch app. I followed the [guide](http://www.rubymotion.com/developers/guides/manuals/cocoa/apple-watch/). Everything is good except for when I try to run the watch app with `rake watch`. It says it cannot find a simulator device. The main app runs fine.

```
[!] Cannot find any simulator devices, please add devices in Xcode -> Window -> Devices.
```

*UPDATE* To clarify: I had watches paired with devices already. Running `rake watch --trace` showed that RubyMotion could not resolve a watch to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting all simulators that Xcode 10 creates by default and trying with an iPhone 6s. In my case, the default simulator that wanted to run was the iPhone 6s but I deleted it to use an iPhone 8 by default. I kept pairing watches with the device until I found that the `Apple Watch Series 2 42mm` worked.

I am only able to run watch apps by pairing `Apple Watch Series 2 42mm` to a simulator.

I can run different simulators using `device_name` and specifying the iPhone device (RubyMotion launches the iPhone and Watch app at the same time). Again, the device specified must have a `Apple Watch Series 2 42mm` paired to be able to run `rake watch device_name="{{DEVICE}}"`.

---

For my iPhone 6s simulator with a Apple Watch Series 2 42mm

```
rake watch device_name="iPhone 6s"
```

---

For my iPhone 8 simulator with a Apple Watch Series 2 42mm

```
rake watch device_name="iPhone 8"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a paired watch to your target iPhone.

1. Select Device and Simulators in Window menu.
2. Choose Simulators segmentation.
3. Select your target iPhone.
4. Click + button in PAIRED WATHES table.
5. Select Apple Watch model which is after series 2.

[add a paired watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3UTt.png)

Comment: I did this already. I had the default devices created by Xcode 10. I added a few different watches to my "default" simulator but the only one that worked was the Apple Watch Series 2 42mm.

Comment: Oh sorry!
I found that my existing app is launchable, but watch app newly creating from a template could not launch by Xcode 10.1. I don't know the difference now.